# Photoimage is not working in tkinter. Gives an error now but from start

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
win = Tk()
colorful=PhotoImage(file='image/1.png')
```

_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "image/1.png" file path is correct, from beginning it was running without an error but when I add some more code it happened, why?

Comment: Are you sure it is PNG image even though its extension is .png?

Comment: Yeah it's .png if not error should be(no such file or directory) as I said it was working but then I add one more png and it appeared. P.S I am using MacOS operating system maybe cause of that?

Comment: What I mean is that the image may not be a PNG image.  Use another image application to check whether it is actually a PNG image.  Or try to use Pillow module instead.

Comment: yeah you are right how to check it as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
img = Image.open("file_name")
colorful = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter Photoimage only supports .gif images.

If you want to display .png images, Use PIL (Python Imaging Library)
Fore more info, see https://pythonbasics.org/tkinter-image/ .

Comment: tkinter.PhotoImage in Python 3 should support PNG image.

Comment: I Agree. Fortunately there is PIL.